# URL rewriting loop for (/.*)

Tags: apache, loops, mod-rewrite

I have to access the following url when I hit:

```
localhost/b/c
redirect to
localhost/a/b/c
```

I tried this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond [%{REQUEST_URI}] !^/?(a(/.*))/?$
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ /a/$1 [R,L]
```

But its only working for `localhost/b`. Not for `localhost/b/c` i.e multiple levels.

```
RewriteCond [%{REQUEST_URI}] !^/?(a(/.*))/?$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/?$ /a/$1 [R,L]
```

This rule is looping and rewriting to url

```
localhost/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/b/c
```

All help is really appreciated. I am new to url rewriting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could work out for you:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?a/.*/?$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /a/$1 [R,L]
```

I think your problem is that you use `[]` in your `RewriteCond` while it should be `{}`.

Also, enabling [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) is good for debugging rewrite rules.

Hope it helps you forward.

Comment: Now I have another issue:
this rule is working in chrome and mozilla but not on IE.
any idea about solution?

Comment: Try enabling the RewriteLog and see if the request differ when using IE. From the top of my head I don't know why IE won't redirect. Caching issues perhaps.

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but you could try to use `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: I always delete cache before trying new rewriterule and also [R=301,L] not working

Comment: I tried it in my IE8, and it's working fine. If `a/b/c` does not exist on the server, and you try to get `b/c` you will not see the `a/b/c` url in the browser though and it still show `b/c`. This is different from Chrome. However if it exist the redirect works fine. Looking in `RewriteLog` I see that the rewrite do what is expected in both cases. Maybe you have the same "issue"?

Comment: I am using IE10 and i have a/b/c in my localhost. And in case of Rewritelog, it is doing what it should do but IE10 is not showing the result

Comment: Sounds like this is a IE10 issue rather than rewrite issue. Maybe new question?

Comment: BTW, there are loads of posts out there regarding IE and redirect problems.

Comment: BTW, for future references it might be good to accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new here. Its an IE bug.